# Managing session in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I am a newbie in Spring, so I am explaining my requirement.

My requirement is to create an web - application in spring, where sign in / log in should be from 1 system. If user gets logged in , in another browser/system the previous should be out of session.

How can I achieve this ? Any document link or any concept that I need to learn will be helpful.

Comment: please check this link https://dzone.com/articles/using-http-session-spring

Comment: this link is also helpful https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/session/spring-session-tutorial/

Comment: @vaibhavpatil- good article

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spring-session-redis](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/spring-session-redis) - it's an API with implementation for managing a user’s session information with [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Application uses command line to execute `GET` request on **same server running on different ports**, to explain how the session works. You can build `POST`, `DELETE` and other `HTTP` request.

Answer (score 0):

HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse interfaces are implemented by the web-container wrapping your application.
If you are using Spring boot it uses embedded Tomcat instance, if you are deploying your WAR application on Weblogic, they are implemented by Weblogic.
However, the interfaces are the same and depending on your configuration on those containers, they maintain Session objects.
Using this session object, you can add key-value pairs and maintain same set coming from the same user in consequent requests.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")     
 public Object hello(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){request.getSession().setAttribute("key",mySessionObject);}
```

when you want to retrieve the session object you have just added, just use getAttribute() method with same key.

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("key")
```